# Running Apache-CXF on WebSphere

Tags: java, xml, apache, websphere, cxf

I'm trying to deploy cxf client on websphere 8.5. I resolved conflicting cxf class issues. Now I'm having issue with `XmlSchemaForm.class` lacking QUALIFIED field. Obviously wrong class is being loaded.

I already set `xmlschema-core-2.0.3.jar` on shared libraries to be loaded on startup.

But when I checked resource path it shows

```
bundleresource://222.fwk-496297919/org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaForm.class
```

instead of jar file path.

I googled and add `DisableIBMJAXWSEngine:true` under manifest.mf to avoid jax-ws annotations but no luck.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find what jar have the wrong class?

Comment: Any luck with this one? I might face similar problem very soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Set parent last as classloader policy

Comment: Did you place  the library inside your ear/war? If not, and you're using ibms shared lib functionality, you could try changing isolation level for your library bundle

Comment: As a side note: you should use osgi